# how to search a json array object in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel-5.6

To search an object in JSON from MYSQL using Laravel you do this:

```
 $parent = DB::table($this->table)
                ->where("right_children->parent", $firstParent)
                ->get();
```

The problem now is how I can go about searching objects in arrays

```
[
    {   "parent": "fish", 
        "children": { "right": "nunu"}
    }, 
    {   "parent": "cat", 
        "children": {"right": "nonha"}
    }
]
```

IF I want to find the name "nunu" how to I search it using laravel?
I tried this:

```
DB::table($this->table)
  ->whereJsonContains("right_children->children->right", $firstParent)
  ->get();
```

but no result, I know I am getting it wrong

Comment: I think, from reading the Laravel manual `whereJsonContains` is specifically for SQL Server and not MySQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly in other words its better done through raw mysql than Laravel?

Comment: Not necessarily. I am not Laravel expert, but this may help you https://www.qcode.in/use-mysql-json-field-in-laravel/